# How do you access physical VisualSVN server files?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I'm wondering how you access the physical files that have been committed to a svn repository? I set my svn repository to D:\repositories at installation and for some reason, I can't find or see any of the files. Is there something that I'm missing?

Answer (score 3):

An SVN repository is not stored in a standard file structure. You should see subdirectories, and inside them are more subdirectories, and inside those are checksum files, binary files, etc.

For more information, you should refer to the [Subversion Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/index.html) - it has a wealth of official information.

If you're looking to get a working copy of the subversion repository for say, running your actual website, then the easiest and safest way to do this is to do an `svn checkout` to a folder on your web server, and point your web server to read the website from that folder. Each time you want to update the website, do an `svn update`. The same principal applies for doing a daily build server (although for a build server you'll want to delete your local working copy first), and many other scenarios.

There are Subversion plugins that will allow you to view the `head` revision as a physical file structure, but I'm uneasy to recommend them, because a single accidental `commit` will bring down your entire scenario.